# How to resolve unity dependency in console app from constructor of new instance

Tags: c#, unity-container

**Background:**

I used Unity IoC only in WPF Application until now.
I would like to use is in a console application.
In the WPF Application runs some "magic" to automatically choose the correct constructor of the new object/instance.

**Question:**

How I use the same "magic" in my console application?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IUnityContainer unitycontainer = new UnityContainer();

    // RegisterType of Dependency in container
    unitycontainer.RegisterType<IMyDependency,Dependency>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

    // How shall I choose the correct constructor?
    // In WPF Application the correct constructor was used automatically
    // How the wpf apps use the correct constructor with my dependencies?
    var newclass = new newclass();
}

public class NewClass
{
     private readonly IMyDependency _dependency;

     public NewClass(IMyDependency dependency)
     {
         _dependency = dependency;
     }
}
```

Comment: Unity will do it for you, just use the API to create the object of the `NewClass`, it will automatically inject dependencies

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. If i try to create my newclass as shown, then the compiler complaines the missing constructor without parameters

Comment: yes because you don't have the zero argument constructor anywhere, why would it allow you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `IUnityContainer.Resolve` to instantiate the class which will call the constructor with the registered dependencies.

`var newclass = unitycontainer.Resolve<NewClass>();`

Comment: I nearly understood, but before I have to register my newclass to the container too?

Comment: Without registering how would it know what to inject

Comment: with unity, you only have to register interfaces, concrete types are implicitly registered